# Sub measure of a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(S,\Sigma, \mu)$ be a finite measure space. Let $\Sigma_0$ be a sub $\sigma$-field of $\Sigma$. Let $\mu_0$ be the restriction of $\mu$ to $\Sigma_0$, i.e $\mu(A)=\mu_0(A)$ for all $A\in \Sigma_0$.

Even though it is trivial, I am trying to prove $\mu_0$ is a measure on the measure space $(S, \Sigma)$.

Should do I check the definition of measure ? or is there any simple way to prove it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Checking the definition is simple enough. All the algebraic properties hold a fortiori.

Another, perhaps more interesting, way is by proving this *push-forward lemma* which generalises the discussion:

> Let $(X,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space, $(Y,\mathcal F,\mu)$ be a measure space and $f:(Y,\mathcal F)\to (X,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable function. Then, $f_*\mu:\mathcal E\to[0,\infty]$ defined by $f_*\mu(A)=\mu(f^{-1}[A])$ is a measure on $(X,\mathcal E)$.

The case $(X,\mathcal E)=(S,\Sigma_0)$, $(Y,\mathcal F,\mu)=(S,\Sigma,\mu)$, $f=id_S$ is yours, since $\mu_0=id_{S*}\mu$.

It is slightly more general, therefore there is a minuscule effort to put (mainly in keeping track of disjunctions), but it is essentially the same difficulty.